# Banach-Mazur distance between Schatten-$p$ classes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Let $M_n$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ complex matrices. Let $1\leq p<\infty.$ For $A\in M_n$ define $\|A\|_p:=(Tr(A^*A)^{p/2})^{1/p}$ where $Tr$ denotes the usual trace of a matrix. Then $\|.\|_p$ is indeed a norm. We write $S_p^n$ to be the Banach space whose vector space is $M_n$ and norm is given by $\|.\|_p.$  Define the Banach-Mazur distance as $d(S_p^n,S_q^n):=\inf\{\|T\|_{S_p^n\to S_q^n}\|T^{-1}\|_{S_q^n\to S_p^n}:T:S_p^n\to S_q^n\ \text{is an invertible linear map}\}.$ Can anyone tell me how does the constant $d(S_p^n,S_q^n)$ behaves as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same order as $d(\ell_p^n, \ell_q^n)$. It is $n^{1/p-1/q}$ when they are on the same side of 2, and $n^{(1/2-1/q)\vee (1/p-1/2)}$ for $1\le p<2<q\le\infty$.

See Section 45 of [Tomczak-Jaegermann's book Banach Mazur distances and Finite dimensional Operator ideals](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Entj/bm_book/index.html) which she made freely available at the link.